# Ember-cli-build, exclude components ember addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I'm using a "core" ember addon in a boilerplate, with

```
npm link core-addon
```

This addon contains generic components, helpers, routes...

Is there a way to exclude some of these components in the boilerplate's ember-cli-build file?

I already tried the following in the ember-build-cli in my boilerplate project, which is probably wrong:

```
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
const environment = EmberApp.env();
module.exports = function (defaults) {
    let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
        funnel: {
                enabled:true,
                exclude:['core-addon/pods/components/pages/**/*']
            },
    });
return app.toTree();
};
```

Ember version: 3.5.0
Ember cli version 3.5.0 node version 8.11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addons generally take the reverse approach of this: The addon manages what gets merged into the consuming app via configuration in the consuming app.

At the highest level, each addon has an entry point that is the `index.js` file sitting in the root directory of the addon. The addon provides certain configuration options that it reads from `config/environment.js` of the consuming app when installing.

I think a really good case study for you would be `ember-bootstrap`. Look at [their configuration options](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/getting-started/setup) and more specifically the `blacklist` option. They allow the consuming application to only install a subset of the bootstrap components. Furthermore, the project supports bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 4, but the consuming app isn't getting both! The work is done in [index.js](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/index.js)

Let's look just at how they blacklist (ie exclude) certain components from being added to the consuming app:

```
treeForApp(tree) {
  tree = this.filterComponents(tree);
  return this._super.treeForApp.call(this, tree);
},
filterComponents(tree) {
  let whitelist = this.generateWhitelist(this.bootstrapOptions.whitelist);
  let blacklist = this.bootstrapOptions.blacklist || [];

  // exit early if no opts defined
  if (whitelist.length === 0 && blacklist.length === 0) {
    return tree;
  }

  return new Funnel(tree, {
    exclude: [(name) => this.excludeComponent(name, whitelist, blacklist)]
  });
}
```

where `this.excludeComponent` at it's core is a boolean returning filter function that returns true if the blacklist contains it in the blacklist case (there for excluding it). The `treeForApp` function returns the tree for all app files, ie what will be merged from the addon's `app` dir into the consuming app:

The consuming app's `ember-cli-build` would look something like this:

```
//your-bootstrap-app/ember-cli-build.js

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-bootstrap': {
      blacklist: ['bs-popover', 'bs-accordion']
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

and the result would be no `bs-popover` and no `bs-accordion` available in the consuming apps app tree. These options are obtained in the `index.js` file like so:

```
let options =Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, app.options['ember-bootstrap']);
this.bootstrapOptions = options;
```

Check this [general guide to building addons](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/writing-addons/) and [the more advanced api](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer,your explanation is a big help.

Comment: I managed to get it working with some minor adjustments to the "excludeComponent" function.